# PyQt4 edit QLineEdit and keep the text

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

Following code creates a Widget with a Button and a LineEdit:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QLabel, QComboBox, QProgressBar, QFileDialog
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSize, pyqtSlot

class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(500, 300, 820, 350)
        self.setWindowTitle("Widget")
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        #Buttons
        btnposx = 30
        btnposy = 50


        leposx = 150
        leposy = btnposy

        self.le = QLineEdit(self)
        self.le.move(leposx,leposy)
        self.le.resize(630,26)

        self.btn = QPushButton('Save',self)
        self.btn.move(btnposx,btnposy)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.edit_le)


        self.show()

    def edit_le(self):
        self.le.setText('hello')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Further with a push on the Button, the LineEdit is filled with 'hello'. Is there a way to Keep the 'hello' string, even if the Widget gets closed?

Edit:

Thank you for the dublicate link eyllanesc. Unfortunately the example code provided in this thread does not seem to work. I adapted it for PyQt4 but it just does not save anything. I am using Spyder.

Comment: Keep it where? What do you plan to do with it? I assume this question is closely related to your [last one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49855172/984421). Please explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This question is not related to my last one. I want my LineEdits to save the entered text, so that when I exit the widget and restart it, the LineEdit still shows the text I entered.

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov 
It seems that you do not know how to implement my solution, besides that, thanks to your question I have been able to solve some compatibility problems between PyQt4 and PyQt5, the solution for your case is as follows: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/c4c75c8b717fbb521b51567b0901b9ae/archive/a097a555a8854caeb1cef1da4f1b849391e08c44.zip

Comment: First of all, thanks for your effort. I tried to execute your code, the window Shows up but does not save anything I type in. Could it be a Problem with Spyder? In Spyder I execute each PyQt Task in a 'new dedicated Python console'. If I would not, Spyder crashes every second time I try to execute PyQt code.

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov 
I have run it with Spyder 3.2.8 on Linux with PyQt4 4.12.1 and it works correctly.

Comment: I can check the version of Spyder and PyQt4 on monday. Will reply. Thanks